# displaying IMAGE IN ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

In ASP.NET when we add image in design page we are getting image but after compilation we are not getting image.  how to get image,what we have to do..

Comment: Can you provide more detail about your problem? It's very hard to answer without more information.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure it exists - try to use the full path to the image.